# "Come back up" or "Let me back up"

Tags: word-usage

A guy's little cousin took (as in "stole") his keycard and the hotel staff wouldn't allow him back up.

> He took my keycard, so the hotel staff wouldn't let me back up

Or

> He took my keycard, so the hotel staff wouldn't let me come back up.

Does the second one work?

Comment: For your information, in informal English "let me back up" would equal "let me come back" up. However, you probably mean: let me (**go**) back up. Otherwise, the person is located below the hotel staff....And if you just use, let me back up, that point becomes moot.

Comment: The ***come/go*** choice is primarily governed by where the speaker is at time of utterance, in relation to the referenced destination. Other than that, it's just that we don't have to include "verbs of motion" such as ***come, go*** in contexts like *Let me [go] out, Let him [come] in.* In OP's *specific* case, ***come*** doesn't actually have to be present at all - but regardless of whether it's there or not, you can have ***either*** or ***both*** of the prepositions ***back*** and ***up*** (but if they're ***both*** present, they must appear in that order).

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: I strongly disagree with @Lambie that "the hotel staff wouldn't let me back up" implies that the speaker is physically below the hotel staff.  "the hotel staff would not let me back up (.... to the room)" is the way most English speakers would interpret that.

Comment: Go or Come depends on the location of the speaker. If you are in a hotel lobby, you would say: let me (go) back up. If you say: The hotel staff would not let me back up. You are up in your room, and they are down in the lobby,. Below you. Mine is the most logical, not yours. For all English speakers.